# Jwplayer mute doesn't work with HLS stream

Tags: jwplayer, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to implement mute button on HLS stream in Jwplayer. I found this example on [official site](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1428525-autostarting-on-page-load). 
I've just copied code:

```
<div id="myElement"></div>

<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
      file: "/uploads/myVideo.mp4",
      width: 640,
      height: 270,
      autostart: true,
      mute: true
    });
</script>
```

and replaced file property on

```
http://android-hd.izletv.mobi:80/org5/trt1_me/chunks.m3u8
```

And on my IPad i still can listen sound. What's the problem?

Comment: You can't really control the volume for mobile Safari, that is what the physical buttons on the device are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/autoloop/

Safari for iOS does not support mute attribute per jwplayer website

[image]

Comment: Sure, I'll accept your answer as site allows it to me. Can you advice me if it's possible anyway to disable sound? Decrease volume for example?
Foun a Volume API, but
Volume

These API calls are used to change the playback volume of the player. Note they only work on desktop browsers, not on mobile devices.

Comment: For a more official reference https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html "On iOS devices, the audio level is always under the user’s physical control. The volume property is not settable in JavaScript. Reading the volume property always returns 1."